# ¿por que switch no esta recibiendo por parametro una variable?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una calculadora en Javascript que usa formulas muy simples pero cuando implemento el switch y le paso como parametro una variable me retorna el default. Aqui esta mi codigo gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

```
const FM_IDEAL = 9
const MINUTOS_DIA = 1440

const mgDextrosaAl5 = 5000
const mgDextrosaAl10 = 10000
const mgDextrosaAl30 = 30000
const mgDextrosaAl50 = 50000
const cien = 100

const botonCalcular =  document.getElementById('botonCalcular')

const initializer = () => {
  botonCalcular.onclick = () => {
    let peso = document.getElementById("peso").value
    let dextrosaNecesaria = FM_IDEAL * MINUTOS_DIA * peso
    let cantidadDextrosaAl5Porciento = (dextrosaNecesaria * cien) / mgDextrosaAl5
    let cantidadDextrosaAl10Porciento = (dextrosaNecesaria * cien) / mgDextrosaAl10
    let cantidadDextrosaAl30Porciento = (dextrosaNecesaria * cien) / mgDextrosaAl30
    let cantidadDextrosaAl50Porciento = (dextrosaNecesaria * cien) / mgDextrosaAl50
    
    let diasDeNacido = document.getElementById("dias").value
    
    let cantidadDeLiquidos = (dias) => {
      switch(dias) {
        case 1:
          return peso * 70      
          break
        case 2:
          return peso * 80
          break
        case 3:
          return peso * 100
          break
        case 4:
          return peso * 125
          break
        case 5:
          return peso * 140
          break
        default:
          console.log('el campo esta vacio')
          break
      }    
    }
    const objetivoLiquidos = document.getElementById('liquidosNecesarios')
    console.log(diasDeNacido)
    objetivoLiquidos.innerHTML = cantidadDeLiquidos(diasDeNacido)


    const objetivo5 = document.getElementById('resultado5')
    objetivo5.innerHTML = `Dextrosa al 5 en cc :----- ${cantidadDextrosaAl5Porciento} CC`
    const objetivo10 = document.getElementById('resultado10')
    objetivo10.innerHTML = `Dextrosa al 10 en cc :----- ${cantidadDextrosaAl10Porciento} CC`
    const objetivo30 = document.getElementById('resultado30')
    objetivo30.innerHTML = `Dextrosa al 30 en cc :----- ${cantidadDextrosaAl30Porciento} CC`
    const objetivo50 = document.getElementById('resultado50')
    objetivo50.innerHTML = `Dextrosa al 50 en cc :----- ${cantidadDextrosaAl50Porciento} CC`
  }  
}

initializer()
```

Aqui esta el HTML por si se necesita

He revisado si el problema es en la obtencion de la variable pero no es, ahi, el problema radica en el switch

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto el problema. Lo que pasa es que Switch solo recibe enteros asi que hice

```
switch(parseInt(dias)) {}
```

y todo se resolvio